# read and write a dataset description as a pandas dataframe "attribute"?

Tags: python, r, pandas, feather

The R-help for `feather_metadata` states "Returns the dimensions, field names, and types; and **optional dataset description**."

@hrbrmstr Kindly posted a [PR](https://github.com/wesm/feather/pull/326) to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896468/how-to-add-optional-dataset-description-to-feather-file/47898172#47898172) SO question and make it possible to add a dataset description to a feather file from R.

I'd like to know if it is possible to read (and write) such a dataset description in python / pandas using `feather.read_dataframe` and `feather.write_dataframe` as well? I searched the documentation but couldn't find any information about this. It was hoping something like the following might work:

```
import feather
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
dat._metadata = "A dataset description ..."
feather.write_dataframe(dat, "pydf.feather")
```

Or else perhaps:

```
feather.write_dataframe(dat, "pydf.feather", "A dataset description ...")
```

Comment: Tis unlikely given: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/238881fae8530a1ae994eb0e283e4783d3dd2855/python/pyarrow/feather.py#L64-L111